# No AJAX effect the second time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am currently building a rating system, using PHP, SQL, jQuery and AJAX.

I works pretty well, except one little detail.
When I rate the first time, the result is successfully sent the the rate.php file, saved in my db, and the new result sent back to my rating page.
But when I try to rate again, nothing happens.

Not even the jQuery "hover effect" works. I have to reload the entire page, before I can rate again.

I've tried to change `on` with `bind` and `click`. To help there.
I've also tried to add `cache: false,` and change `success` to `done`, and finally also the `document.getById` with `content.html(result);`

I'm pretty new for ajax, so maybe there is a much easier way to do this.

I have heard a bit about something called JSON, but I don't know if that will work with this.

---

Here's my jQuery and AJAX on site.php:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('span').hover(function() {
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().toggleClass('my');

});



$('span').on('click', function() {

    // Define data to send
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
    var star = $(this).attr("class");

    // Put data together and send request with ajax
    var post = "id="+id+"&stars="+star;
    $.ajax( {
        url:"includes/rate.php",
        cache: false,
        data: post,
        success:function(result) {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=result;
        }

     });    

});

});
```

The PHP that loads the current rating on site.php:

http://pastie.org/private/qql0ajaq9lfjqmisgvmzkq

and the rate.php:

http://pastie.org/private/kgufwlmx69t8vxjugx9zyg

Hope someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing your elements and this is causing your click event handlers to stop. Try attaching the click handler to the document instead.

Change:

```
$('span').on('click', function() {
```

To:

```
$(document).on('click', 'span', function() {
```

Also in your code since you're using jQuery you can change this:

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=result;
```

To:

```
$('#' + id).html(result);
```

Comment: amazing! The Ajax Call works perfect now :D - But how do I get the hover effects to work? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should bind on elements that are always present in the DOM. I tend to just use `document`.

```
$(document).on('click', 'span', function(){
  // Code here
});
```

This way you wont lose the event once the HTML is replaced in the AJAX call